# Insert image in PDF file

Tags: php, pdf

I need to insert an image in a PDF file on a certain page, in a specific location. How could I do that in a way that would work on a server. I'm looking for a command-line application, windows if possible. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How about using the PHP PDF extension? http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-load-image.php

Comment: Give [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) a try. There is also a post [here](http://pranavom.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/modify-pdf-using-fpdffpdi-library/) in which the process of modifying an existing PDF file in order to add i.e an image is described. The code can be made a standalone script in order to run it from command line

Comment: What has that got to do with PHP, if you want a console application or a windows application?

Comment: If there was a pure php solution even better...

Comment: Console application for windows os...

Comment: TCPDF or FDPF, as the PDF engine, both can use [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) which is a template engine over the top of either, that allows additions to existing pages.