# How can I add an image to an existing PDF template page containing form fields?

Tags: image, forms, pdf, imagemagick

I'm doing a document scanning project that involves inserting a scanned image into an existing PDF template page that contains form fields. I've used ImageMagick to take process the scan, and then append a raster image of the form template to the bottom, and convert that image into a PDF. However, forms and checkbox fields have to be added manually to the resulting PDF. Below is a sample of my ImageMagick command.

```
convert inputScan.jpg -resize 975x420 FormTemplate.png -append CombinedFile.pdf
```

Ideally, I would run a command that would take the JPG scan and the PDF template file containing fields, and output a PDF file with the scan at the top of a page and the field-containing template text below it. The closest thing I could find to a solution was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567031/insert-image-in-pdf-file), but PHP can't be used on the computer in question.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!